# Joining 3 tables using SQL Query?

Tags: ms-access

I'm having problems joining three tables. It works well when I use the same query for joining two tables (after removing `LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.No = C.No`). However, it doesn't work when I use three tables.

This is my query

```
SELECT A.Name, B.Quantity, C.Quantity 
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B 
    ON A.ID = B.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN C 
    ON B.No = C.No;
```

Comment: If you set up your joins using Design View of the Access query designer, it will add the parentheses Access requires when the `FROM` clause includes more than one join.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MS-Access is rather picky at how it wants the joins to be formed. Add parentheses:

```
SELECT A.Name, B.Quantity, C.Quantity 
FROM 
  ( A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID )
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.No = C.No ;
```

Standard SQL syntax - and most other DBMS - do not need require parentheses in the `FROM` clause, although you are allowed to use them for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked! Thank you so much. I knew my query was right, just missed out the parenthesis. Thanks once again. God bless! :)

Comment: Most other DBMS do not need these (and rightfully so).

Comment: Yes. It's my first time using MS Access. I'm just so used to SQL Server!

Comment: @deppz: You know there is an SQL-Server Express edition? (not with the full capabilities of the higher editions but it may serve your needs).

Comment: Yes I've used that before. For this particular task I only had to use MS Access. Thanks for your suggestion though.